# The cin.getline() should not accept space if user inputs?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class acc_cr{
protected:
  char username[100];
  char password[100];
  int i = 0;
public:
  void create(){
      fstream fout;
      //new username:
      cout<<"Enter Your New Username:\n";
      while(i == 0){
        cin.getline(username,100);
        //checking if this username already exists:
        if(fstream(username)){
          cout<<"Username Already Exists!\nTry Another Username:\n";
        }
        else{
          fout.open(username,ios::out);//creating new file to store contents
          break;
        }
      }
    //new password:
    cout<<"Enter Your New Password:\n";
    cin.getline(password,100);

    //inserting data into csv file:
    fout<<username<<","
        <<password<<"\n";
  }
};
```

If any user inputs username or password which is asked by the above program the program accepts it but the problem here is i don't want this program to accept space as well...the program should accept if the user typed "myusername" and not "my username"....if they typed "my username"the program should show error that please dont enter space....I recently started using cin.getline() because cin was performing even worse in the above situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `cin.getline(username, 100,' ')` the input is automatically terminated if the user enters a string. But I really don't suggest that because it spoils the whole experience for the user.

The best solution I suggest is to use `std::string` instead of `char` array. Then you will be able to use `stringstream`.

```
    string username;
        .
        .
        .

cout<<"Enter Your New Username:\n";
      while(i == 0){
        getline(cin,username);

        stringstream check(username);
         string intermediate; 
    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space ' ' 


 //Extracting the username up to first space
    getline(check, intermediate,' ');

//Checking if anything is there after first space
    if(getline(check, intermediate,' ')){
          cout<<"Invalid Username-contains spaces!\nTry Another Username:\n";
        }


        //checking if this username already exists:
        else if(fstream(username)){
          cout<<"Username Already Exists!\nTry Another Username:\n";
        }
        else{
          fout.open(username,ios::out);//creating new file to store contents
          break;
        }
      }
```

For more info on `std::getline`, visit [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

To learn strings (which are way cooler than `char` arrays, go [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

And this one is for the coolest of all, [using stringstream to tokenize a string](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/tokenizing-a-string-cpp/amp/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15892709550006&amp_ct=1589270955354&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Ftokenizing-a-string-cpp%2F)

Comment: Wow....excellent answer...and also thanks for the materials....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, you may want to make use of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) like:

```cpp
std::string username;
std::getline(std::cin, username);

if (username.find(' ') != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Username should not contain spaces!" << std::endl;
}
```

Read about [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)